# getFormAction() returns empty string

Tags: php-5.4, forms

I am embedding the contacts form onto a CMS page with this bit of layout XML:

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="core/template" name="cmsContactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"></block>
</reference>
```

However, when I am on that CMS page this bit of code on the contacts form page:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

The `getFormAction()` method returns an empty string, resulting in the contact form failing as it just refreshes the page instead of submitting the information in the contact form.

Can anyone tell me how to get a proper form action from `getFormAction()`?

Is there a relevant helper that I can employ on a CMS page?

Comment: Is this Magento 1.9?

Answer (score 0):

In Magento post action for contact page is set in controller class

```
Mage_Contacts_IndexController
```

In action `indexAction()`

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('contactForm')
            ->setFormAction( Mage::getUrl('*/*/post', array('_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure())) );
```

If you declare the post action in block xml

```
<block type="core/template" name="cmsContactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"></block>
```

You can get it in block file which you are using as `core/template` and you can not get it in phtml directly.

**You can use directly like**

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('contacts/index/post', array('_secure' => $this->getRequest()->isSecure())); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Comment: But this is not an answer to the question. Do you know the answer to get the form action properly?

Comment: If you are sure this is not a correct answer to question, you must know proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of core/template use contact block for get this function